# I can't use IF in GEE, it's very strange

Tags: google-earth-engine

As you can see, the result is 'yes', but my flag is 0, how could this happen? What can I do?

[image]

```
var img=imageCollection.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2021-08-09','2021-08-10').median();
print(img)
var flag=img.bandNames().size();
print(flag);

if(flag)
{
  print('yes')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343946/using-if-else-structure-in-google-earth-engine. Just write "if statement with gee" in google...

Comment: Can you share your code?